# Issue with "org.eclipse.jdt.launching.IVMInstall.getLibraryLocations()"

Tags: java

When I try to run my Java program in Eclipse I get the following error:

"An internal error occurred during: "Launching ConvertExcelToJSON".
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.jdt.launching.IVMInstall.getLibraryLocations()" because "install" is null"

I have never seen the error before, the program has run with no problem before. Yesterday I got updates to my work machine and maybe that caused something to give me this error.

Anyone seen this before and perhaps have a solution to it?

Comment: It's fixed. The question can be discarded.

Comment: It would be better if you wrote down what went wrong as answer and self-accept it. Maybe it's information that someone in future will appreciate ;)

Answer (score 24):

It happened after I changed my `Installed JREs` configuration. Eclipse's default bundled JRE 16 was selected in IDE's `Run Configurations`, but my project was set to Java 8 everywhere in project configurations(maven etc).
**Following fixed my case:**
Go to `Run > Run Configurations` then go to `JRE` tab and update the project JRE according to new configuration. So that JRE version in eclipse matches the project requirements.
[image: Go to Run>Run Configurations. Go to JRE tab. And fix the JRE setting]

Answer (score 10):

In my case, there was a difference in project's execution environment and installed JDK.

I changed it from Right Click on Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> JRE System Libraries -> Select same version as installed JDK and it worked.

Comment: this helped me find my problem though my solution was a little different and I hope this helps someone. Background - work told me to move over to Azul java and so I had to change my JRE. When  I got the same error as the OP I followed the path given by @Anuja and found I had some old-version JRE system libraries red-flagged and Azul's JRE was acceptable to the build path. I deleted the old ones and it all worked again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the root cause was that my ant build launch configuration was set to a separate JRE than the workspace, and that JRE was removed.

To fix it, I opened the properties of the build.xml file, selected the 'Run/Debug Settings', edited the launch configuration, and then in the JRE tab, set it to use the workspace JRE.