# Unable To Run Maven Install and Maven Clean

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have a Maven project opened in the latest version of Eclipse, but am having a difficult time executing the following commands when I right-click on the project and hover over "Run As":
Maven install
Maven clean

I have attached an image of me trying to execute Maven clean.
[image: Maven Clean Shown]

When I run "Maven install" I get the following error:
An internal error occurred during: "Launching Executing install in D__Java Softwares_2023Jan-Ireland-Maven".
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.jdt.launching.IVMInstall.getLibraryLocations()" because "install" is null

When I run "Maven clean" I get the following error:
An internal error occurred during: "Launching Executing clean in D__Java Softwares_2023Jan-Ireland-Maven".
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.jdt.launching.IVMInstall.getLibraryLocations()" because "install" is null

The following is an image of the libraries listed under the Java Build Path:
[image: Java Build Path Libraries]

The following is an image of the JRE selected:
[image: Selected JRE]

Please help me understand what could be the problem that is causing these issues.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69266228/issue-with-org-eclipse-jdt-launching-ivminstall-getlibrarylocations ?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately I have already done this, but it still gives me the same errors.

Comment: Your image of the libraries listed under the Java Build Path does not, in fact, show any libraries. What's listed on your Installed JREs preference page?

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, there was a difference in project's execution environment and installed JDK.
I needed to change it from Right Click on Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> JRE System Libraries -> Select same version as installed JDK and it worked.